# Error in code for opening txt file and creating a value returning function

Tags: c++

So I'm supposed to open a file containing four emails under "sender", either a 'C' or 'W' for "type", a size, and the classification of it being small, medium, or large should be determined by a value determined function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

string classification(int size);

int main ()
{
    ifstream infile;
    int size1, total_sender = 0, total_size = 0, total_small = 0;
    char type;
    string class, sender;

infile.open("eMail.txt");
    if(!infile) {
        cout << "Error opening file!";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "TYPE" << "SENDER" << "SIZE" << "CLASSIFICATION" << endl;

    infile >> type >> sender >> size1;
    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        class = classification(size1);
        cout << type << sender << size1 << class << endl;
        total_sender += sender;
        total_size += size1;
        if (class == "SMALL")
            total_small++;
    }

    cout << "Total emails: " << total_sender << endl;
    cout << "Total KBs: " << total_size << endl;
    cout << "TOtal SMALL emails: " << total_small << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I was actually supposed to return either an 'L', 'M', or 'S' but chose to do this instead, could it be a major problem?

```
string classification(int size)
{
    if (size < 5) {
        cout << "SMALL";
    else if (size >=5 && size <= 20)
        cout << "MEDIUM";
    else
        cout << "LARGE";
    }
}
```

The code doesn't work and I need some help!

Thank you in advance.

Ok so I edited the definition to

```
char classification(int size)
{
    if (size < 5) {
        return 'S';
    else if (size >=5 && size <= 20)
        return 'M';
    else
        return 'L';
    }
}
```

Comment: The `while (!infile.eof())` loop appears to be endless, and sending data to `cout` is not the same as returning it.

Comment: @RetiredNinja how can i not make it infinite

Answer (score 0):

Printing a string to the screen with `cout` is not the same as returning it to the caller.  Your `classification` function needs to return a value using the `return` keyword.

Also, you can't have a variable named `class` in C++, since that's a keyword.

Comment: Yes and don't do `while (!infile.eof())`

Comment: i used something else in my actual code i just typed it up fast here  and shortened variables

Comment: The loop checking for `!infile.eof()` doesn't read data from `infile`, giving it no reason to stop once it enters. And using `cout` directly in a getter function will cause you headaches. You don't want to take any final decision in a tiny function like that.

Comment: how can i refrain from my while loop being endless @Frederik.L

Comment: To be able to end, a loop must have a condition that will eventually get true. The condition `infile.eof()` is checking if you have reached the end of the stream. Therefore, unless you read into that stream "while" your condition isn't met, it won't ever end. This is a good practice to read AND check the stream at the same time to avoid endless loops. For example, instead of `while (!infile.eof())`, you should use : `while (infile >> type >> sender >> size1)`. That will check the validity of operator>> in the current state of the stream, as well as reading your data.